# Правильное построение предложения

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте, хотелось бы узнать. Как правильно говорится "та, которая ждёт", или "та, кто ждёт"?

Comment: Пишите, как Вам кажется правильным.

Answer (score 3):

Оба варианта возможные. Смысл у них отличается. 
Та, что/кто ждет - эпитет.
Которая ждет - одна из многих.

Насчет стиля - не думаю. Если и было когда-то, то сейчас "та, кто" вполне уместно в любом стиле кроме научного.

Comment: Загадочный ответ.

>Та, что/кто ждет - эпитет.  

Расшифруйте свое неожиданное определение! Что такое эпитет, и где он здесь прячется? *Кто/что/который ждет* - придаточное определительное предложение, только и всего.

>Которая ждет - одна из многих.

Тоже расшифруйте смысл утверждения. Одна из многих - это что означает без контекста? Она одна ждет, или они все вместе кого-то ждут? А если это единственная женщина во всем мире - та, которая ждет отверженного всеми изгоя...
Любой текст обладает своим стилем. Без примеров не обойтись, Вы их не привели, Ваши утверждения голословны.

Comment: Без проблем. Вот пример: "Неважно, есть ли у тебя своя семья. Есть та, кто\которая будет ждать твоего звонка!".

Comment: А где сама Ирина) Жду ее серьезных разъяснений (кто-эпитет против которой-многой)

Comment: Кто из них (этих женшин на остановке) ваша жена? - Та, которая ждет.
Какую жену вы бы хотели иметь? - Ту, кто/что ждет.

Не знаю, что тут еще разъяснять.

Comment: Да уж... Вопросов больше не имею.

Answer (score 2):

Очень интересный вопрос!
Стихи серебряного века русской поэзии :

> М. А. Кузмин. «Не верю солнцу, что идет к закату...» (1908-1909)
> Когда придешь ты в светлую долину,
> Узнаешь там, **как тот, кто ждет**, полюбит.

Слова из советской песни :

> **Тот кто ждет** все снесет как бы жизнь не била
> Лишь бы все это все не напрасно было

Из современной статьи :

> Юлия Кантор. Вячеслав Тихонов: «Я ушел совсем в другую жизнь». Тайна встречи Штирлица с женой (2003) // «Известия», 2003.02.05 Это нужно было представить: та женщина, которую любил, **та, которая ждет**, о которой ты только помнишь, она уже только образ…

Почему-то все примеры на одну тему (??)

Вот что мне подумалось. ***Та, кто ждет*** - это высокий стиль, поэтический, про ба-а-альшую любовь. ***Та, которая ждет*** - средний стиль, журнально-прозаический, типа того))) А вот если девушка ждет общественный транспорт на остановке, и молодой человек скажет о ней приятелю : "Та, **что** ждет трамвая? да я с ней два года учился!" - это без сомнения разговорный стиль.